# Replacing string consisting of mostly metacharacters

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file containing dozens of lines following the below format:

```
source ../foo/bar
source ../foo1/bar1
source ../foo2/bar2
etc
```

I've been puzzling through using sed to find the `source ../foo/` part and replace it with nothing in order to delete it. I've been reading [this very helpful post on the unix/linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script) about escaping meta characters and the resulting regex is:

```
source \.\.\/\.\*?\/
```

Following the instruction from that post, my complete sed looks like this:

```
sed -i 's/source \.\.\/\.\*?\///' TARGETFILE
```

The command completes with no errors, but the file is untouched. I have also tried:

```
sed -i 's/source \.\.\/\.\*?\//''/' TARGETFILE
```

I'm sure I'm making an assumption on something or a syntax error, but I'm sure many of you can appreciate the difficulty of spotting the error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i 's+source \.*/[^/]*/++' TARGETFILE
```

That deletes any leading dots, a slash, a path component and a slash.

Using `+` instead of `/` as a delimitor makes it a bit simpler to match `/`.

`\.*` matches a sequence of dots. `[^/]` matches anything but `/`.

```
sed 's+source \.*/[^/]*/++' <<EXAMPLE
source ../foo/bar
source ..../baz/fop
source /buzz/this/that
EXAMPLE
```

results in

```
bar
fop
this/that
```

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I was making it too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

To delete those lines having pattern `source ../.*/` you can just use `d` command in `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '\~source \.\./[^/]*/~d' file
```

Using `grep` you can avoid using `regex`:

```
grep -vF 'source ../' file
```